# Comparison of two 2d top down player movement scripts in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, rpg

I have been following along two different tutorials on making an 2d RPG and comparing the two movement scripts that seem to do the same thing but in different ways. Which is a better way when comparing these scripts?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < -0.5f){
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
        }

        if(Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") < -0.5f){
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
        }

        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }
}
```

Script 2:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody2D rbody;
    Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector2 movement_vector = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        if (movement_vector != Vector2.zero) {
            anim.SetBool ("Iswalking", true);
            anim.SetFloat ("Input_x", movement_vector.x);
            anim.SetFloat ("Input_y", movement_vector.y);
        } else {
            anim.SetBool ("Iswalking", false);
        }

        rbody.MovePosition (rbody.position + movement_vector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? Unless you define that, it's impossible for anyone to give you proper answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you're comparing `transform.Translate()` with `rigidbody.MovePosition()`.

As you probably know, **transform** represents the **coordinate information of the object** (position, rotation, scale), whereas the **rigidbody** is used to **control the position of the object through physics**.

So, the first knows nothing about physics, the second does. If you are using physics you may bump into glitches if you're using `transform.Translate()`, `rigidbody.MovePosition()` on the contrary handles correctly physics situation.

Collisions between objects moved around using `transform.Translate()`, for example, may result in unwanted overlaps of objects.

Comment: Re: your PS, `Time.deltaTime` returns `Time.fixedDeltaTime` when called during the `FixedUpdate()` phase.

Comment: Doh! You are absolutely right and I'm clearly still a noob :/ Gonna delete that post scriptum...